# datasets module in python for imagenet

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

In one of the programs, author uses the following code to input imagenet

```
from datasets import imagenet
names = imagenet.create_readable_names_for_imagenet_labels()
```

Due to some system constraints, I cannot have `datasets` module installed. Are there any walk-around so that I can get the `names` from imagenet?

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't be able to import datasets, but the source code says that it's based on https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data/build_imagenet_data.py#L463. You could copy the code and modify it for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks, I copied the code, and it works now.